# nginx сайт слетает

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos

Apache MPM-Prefork 2.4.6-45.el7.centos , PHP module 5.6.30-1.el7.remi , PHP-FPM 5.6.30-1.el7.remi , awstats 7.4-1.el7 , logrotate 3.8.6-12.el7 , nginx 1.10.2-1.el7.centos.ngx
Это лог файл с журнала

```
2017/02/19 14:21:12 [error] 590#590: *10205 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:21:14 [error] 590#590: *10207 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:21:19 [error] 590#590: *10209 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:21:43 [error] 590#590: *10224 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:21:45 [error] 590#590: *10226 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.107.9.96, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "http://www.google.ru/search?output=search&q=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%0D"
2017/02/19 14:21:48 [error] 590#590: *10228 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:21:48 [error] 590#590: *10230 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:21:48 [error] 590#590: *10232 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:22:03 [error] 590#590: *10244 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:22:09 [error] 588#588: *10249 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:22:09 [error] 588#588: *10251 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:22:12 [error] 588#588: *10253 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:22:30 [error] 588#588: *10268 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.87.3.88, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "http://www.google.ru/search?output=search&q=%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B%0D"
2017/02/19 14:22:31 [error] 588#588: *10270 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.54, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "79.174.76.93"
2017/02/19 14:22:33 [error] 588#588: *10272 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /wp-admin/post.php?post=69896&action=edit HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/wp-admin/post.php?post=69896&action=edit"
2017/02/19 14:22:33 [error] 588#588: *10274 connect() to unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 178.185.15.3, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "http://google.ru/"
2017/02/19 14:25:46 [error] 588#588: *10272 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:25:46 [error] 588#588: *10277 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D69896%26action%3Dedit HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk"
2017/02/19 14:27:16 [error] 588#588: *10290 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:27:25 [error] 588#588: *10288 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /?customize_changeset_uuid=067dae55-5953-4af4-aa02-6f267818ece6&customize_theme=nanomag&customize_messenger_channel=preview-0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D69896%26action%3Dedit"
2017/02/19 14:53:29 [error] 587#587: *10912 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /shop/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8c%d0%b5/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba/ysl-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1-gloss-volupte-%e2%84%96-210/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:54:05 [error] 588#588: *10949 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /shop/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8c%d0%b5/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba/artdeco-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-2step-gel-lacquer-stay-shine-top-coat-6-%d0%bc%d0%bb/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:54:33 [error] 589#589: *11033 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:54:33 [error] 590#590: *11090 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.118.157.149, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "http://www.google.ru/search?output=search&q=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%0D"
2017/02/19 14:54:33 [error] 589#589: *11047 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:54:33 [error] 589#589: *11082 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /product-category/black-star/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:54:33 [error] 587#587: *10912 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET /shop/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8c%d0%b5/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1/%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba/ysl-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1-gloss-volupte-%e2%84%96-210/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/"
2017/02/19 14:54:33 [error] 587#587: *11086 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.111.230.48, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock:", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "http://google.ru/"
2017/02/19 15:05:13 [error] 579#579: *250 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.volshebnayakarta.tk%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1"
2017/02/19 15:08:17 [error] 579#579: *250 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 81.163.69.136, server: volshebnayakarta.tk, request: "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock", host: "www.volshebnayakarta.tk", referrer: "https://www.volshebnayakarta.tk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.volshebnayakarta.tk%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1"
```

Это конфиг сайта

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 10240k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 10240k;
fastcgi_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=2 keys_zone=example:16m max_size=512m inactive=1d;
server {
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    server_name volshebnayakarta.tk www.volshebnayakarta.tk;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/volshebnayakarta.tk/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/volshebnayakarta.tk.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/volshebnayakarta.tk.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/goldbase/data/www/volshebnayakarta.tk;
    root $root_path;
    expires 1h;




    location ~ /\. {
                deny all; # запрет для скрытых файлов
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all; # запрет для загруженных скриптов
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                expires max; # кеширование статики
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # permalinks
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@volshebnayakarta.tk";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    listen мой ip :80;
    listen мой ip:80;
}
server {
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    server_name volshebnayakarta.tk www.volshebnayakarta.tk;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/goldbase/volshebnayakarta.tk_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/goldbase/volshebnayakarta.tk_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/volshebnayakarta.tk/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/volshebnayakarta.tk.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/volshebnayakarta.tk.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/goldbase/data/www/volshebnayakarta.tk;
    root $root_path;
    listen [2a01:d8:4:2::50f]:443;
    listen мой ip :443;
    expires 1h;

    location ~ /\. {
                deny all; # запрет для скрытых файлов
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all; # запрет для загруженных скриптов
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                expires max; # кеширование статики
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # permalinks
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@volshebnayakarta.tk";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/goldbase.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
}
```

это конфиг nginx

```
user  apache;
worker_processes  4;
timer_resolution 100ms;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
worker_priority -5; #Увеличитвваем приоритет

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}


http {


    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip   on;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    #gzip_disable   "msie6";  #Быстрее, но работает только на новых версиях nginx
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_vary       on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
    server {
        server_name localhost;
 disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location @fallback {
        error_log /dev/null crit;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        access_log off ;
    }
    listen 80;
    }

}
```

Comment: А зачем вам apache при наличии nginx?

Answer (score -1):

Есть несколько причин почему PHP-FPM достигает максимума в pm.max_children:

- слишком много паралелльных запросов,
- слишком медленно выполняются скрипты,
- или слишком маленькое значение.

увеличьте max_children, только следите чтоб у вас памяти хватило на все.